# LED Spot and LED Strip dimming problem

Tags: pwm, led-strip

I have two 555 timer circuits, each one identical to the circuit below but the "load" is different in each circuit. In the first timer circuit, the "load" is 6 x 2m 12V LED strips (10W/m) that are connecting in parallel (built into some shelves). The the second time circuit, the "load" is 12x1W mini LED spots, in parallel (again built into shelving).

[image]

I don't have the model number of the power supply that I am running these from I have had it driving all of the strip and spots directly without a problem (I can attach an image if that helps). I believe is rated to 20A / 240W so on paper it is easily capable enough to drive the strips and spots together.

If I connect either the strips OR the spots, everything works fine and I can control the brightness of the strips or spots by twiddling the 100k pot.

However, if I connect both 555 circuits to the power supply at the same time, the strips start to flicker (the spots seem ok).

Next step I got myself a second 12V power supply, lower power, and drove the spot circuit from that, I kind of thought that would help to 'isolate' the circuits. It helps, but it doesn't solve the problem entirely.

I have a small oscilloscope, I attached it to the output on 555 on the circuit which controls the strips, I can certainly see it 'jumping' from time to time when strips flicker slightly.

Also, if I connect the spots to 12V directly (so no PWM), the problem goes away.

Can anyone help me understand what my next steps should be to try and solve the flickering issue?

Many thanks

Comment: What 555 are you using?

Comment: In the cases where you notice flickering taking place, are both systems being PWM'd? Or put another way, is it the case that flicker isn't ever observed if you operate only one (or zero) systems with PWM and the other one isn't being PWM'd but instead just operated at 100% duty? What frequency are things set for, roughly?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for taking the time to respond. I am using a 'NE555P'. Yes, exactly, I only see the problem with both systems are being PWM'd. In fact I only see to see the issue with the strips, the spots seem unaffected. If I unplug the circuit with the spots, the strips cease to flicker. If I 'un-PWM' the spots but plugging them directly into the same 12V power supply as the strips, the strips cease to flicker. The PWM frequency comes out to around 160Hz with the circuit above.  Tempted to buy a better quality 12V supply but unsure whether that is likely to make a difference. Thanks!